# Seriously? Have I done something wrong?

Tags: discussion, reputation

[How did plants adapated to past CO2 levels? Why won't they do it again?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/how-did-plants-adapt-to-small-sfco-2-levels-past-400k-years-why-wont-they/15852#15852)

**Upgraded:** 
i know i did that artistic trick about pigs (Portugal, Italy, Greece, Spain), but well i am not a bad guy.
i received a positive at least. Well it is something for human resources. i will probably do not answer a lot more anyhow. My geology is being forbiden, four years since graduation and i only read machine learning system and so now. i found it was strange, because i have studied a bit of Paleoclimate at EPOC, Bordeaux, and that is what happens. i don't know if the english is poor in this one too. This one may need edition too.

**Original after deleting some uncomprensible things i wrote maniatic** i think it is my best answer ever, even it is biology stack related,but ES are multidisciplinar.
i am thinking on studing a bit the topic, and give a more accurated answer, as i was a bit K stratego being posted at the excelent Pleistocene Hammen's answer, that didn't answer the question this time. He is surely bussy and he should write very quickly to profite his time at the site.

---

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea what you are talking about.

Comment: The unclear formatting and punctuation makes it hard to get to the gist of what you're saying, but it seems you're wondering why an answer received negative feedback? Except it didn't, it's standing at 0 score with 0 downvotes or upvotes as of now. Or did you mean that you triggered a ban warning by *"and i ask myself ¿block?. It is going to be my last answer probably on my "cv""*? I would find that rather odd unless you have a large number of undeleted, poorly received answers.

Comment: Gramminiae is crucial in this question. Also perennial flora should be quoted. I know this is not biology stack, but well I am pigheaded and also it would be a bit more fair with Hammen if I investigate a bit more and post a more complete answer, so I will do it, receiving positives or no wich doesn't matter a lot in my case. I joke a bit with my reputation in fact :)

Comment: i will nevertheless make some complementary comments and help a bit closing those questions. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys because I was a bit frustrated. I was drinking a lot of beers and that shoted my second disorder besides asperger: schizoaffective. Now I understand my answers are well punctuated for a non english native speaker that has not done investigatio, neither teaching, in geology.

I have been for two months at hospital and completely leave alcohol so I will try to be active on the forum being quiet.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have done nothing wrong.

All I can see is that [your answer](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/15852/6) was automatically flagged by the system because of many user edits, but this is fully automatic and not a dramatic problem.

Please don't worry.  If moderators believe a user is doing something wrong one of us will contact them directly to discuss the situation.

However, I don't understand the second and third section of your meta question here.  What does cannabis have to do with it?

Comment: I have deleted it. Yesterday it was late. I work until 1am, and lupulus is also a Cannabacea and I have troubles to sleep.

Comment: What are the consequences of that? It can't be edited or voted I guess (?). I can see it myself. It is important for me my boss can view it (?). And also I would like to edit it myself after investigating a bit.

Comment: @Universal_learner As far as I know, the only consequence of that flag is that the moderators get a notification and one of us checks that everything is OK. I think this flagging exists because in some cases, when a user edits their post very often, it shows a problem. In this case it was fine, no problem. Only the moderators can see that your post was flagged, users with >2k can see your post under "most edited" in "moderator tools", but anybody who cares to check the history can see [all previous revisions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/15852/revisions).

Comment: @Universal_learner If you have strong reasons to have a certain revision permanently deleted/redacted (such as accidentally posting information online that should not be), please flag the post and one of the moderators can consider it, because by default, all previous revisions are visible to anybody (although not easy to find as I don't think they're indexed by search engines).

Comment: I cannot delete it gerrit. For my part no prob at all (sunglasses). Also maybe Muze read it and give me my second green answer, so it migth be useful finaly.